# How to know the arguments to pass to the client of the callback when calling a webservice method?

Tags: node.js, soap

I want to consume a webservice method through `Nodejs`. This is the wsdl : https://www.telma.net/sentimsa/mvola/wsdl.php?module=jWSDL&action=WSDL:wsdl&service=mvola~WSMVolaGetInfosKYC

I saw [this tutorial](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap) on GitHub. My problem is I do not know where do they know the `['StockQuote']['StockQuoteSoap']` arguments of the client parameter of the callback ! The last argument `['GetQuote']` is perhaps the service method. So in my case how to write the client method calling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I `console.dir`ed your WSDL and saw these two functions:

```
getInfosKYC: [Function],
WSMVolaGetInfosKYCCtrl: { WSMVolaGetInfosKYCCtrlPort: { getInfosKYC: [Function] } },
```

Also, `console.dir(Object.keys(client))` can reveal there are only 2 functions that contain the service names.

```
[ '_events',
  '_eventsCount',
  '_maxListeners',
  'wsdl',
  'soapHeaders',
  'httpHeaders',
  'bodyAttributes',
  'xmlHandler',
  'getInfosKYC',
  'WSMVolaGetInfosKYCCtrl',
  'httpClient' ]
```

Maybe then your syntax will be,

```
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
// wsdl of the web service this client is going to invoke. For local wsdl you can use, url = './wsdls/stockquote.wsdl'
var url = 'https://www.telma.net/sentimsa/mvola/wsdl.php?module=jWSDL&action=WSDL:wsdl&service=mvola~WSMVolaGetInfosKYC';

var requestArgs = {
    module:'jWSDL',
    action:'WSDL:wsdl',
    service:'mvola~WSMVolaGetInfosKYC'
};

var options = {};
soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
  var method = client['WSMVolaGetInfosKYCCtrl']['WSMVolaGetInfosKYCCtrlPort']['getInfosKYC'];
  console.dir(client);//here
  method(requestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
    //response envelope
    console.log('Response Envelope: \n' + envelope);
    //'result' is the response body
    console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

(Too much content to post as a comment, will remove the answer if doensn't work)

Comment: what do you mean by `console.dir` ?

Comment: `console.dir(client);` to see what is in the `client` object.

Comment: if you `console.dir(Object.keys(client))` you can immidiately see that 2 of the keys contain service names. Others are default properties of the wsdl.

Comment: I will test your code , and after 4 days perhaps I will tell you the response because I will be in vacations tomorrow and after tomorrow :)